# apt-get upgrade stalled

Tags: apt, server, upgrade

So I was attempting to upgrade my php version to the latest php7.1 release and tried to do a `apt-get upgrade`as I had `199 packages can be updated`. During the upgrade process I had a GUI screen with "Configuring unattended-upgrades" but I could not select anything at all. I had several options but enter, spacebar, and any other keystroke would not work. I hit `control+z` and ran the `jobs` command and I see this.

`[1]+  Stopped                 sudo apt-get upgrade`

I tried to run `fg` and `fg %1` but it is now just showing `sudo apt-get upgrade` on the new line and nothing is happening. How can I continue the upgrade process or restart/abort the current process? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sudo pkill apt-grep` or `sudo killall apt-grep` should kill the apt-get process. Then you should be able to simply run the command again. Note that recent Ubuntu has switched to `apt` in place of `apt-get` ( prefer `aptitude`). When you ran `fg` you probably wouldn't get any output until apt-get was downloading, or until the download had finished.  Just FWIW you can `sudo apt install php7.1` you don't have to `upgrade` in full.

Comment: @pbhj Thank you for the help. I was able to kill the process and ran `sudo apt install php7.1` it looks like it downloaded `php7.1_7.1.17-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_all.deb` and I restarted my server, but when running `php -v` I still . get `7.1.1-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1` Do you mind telling me how to load the new php version?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php might have enough to get you going; or ask another question. You probably would need to restart not only the server (apache?) but also the php service; I'd reboot once you're sure that the php the server uses is updated - phpinfo() should tell you IIRC.